# Add External users to SharePoint User Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, pnp

I have created Html form with Email,Name etc.

Accordingly form details i want to add user in SharePoint Site Group.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your html page on other application or a SharePoint page (with anonymous access allowed)?

Comment: Html Page is Not in SharePoint or another application

Comment: Then where is it? how will users access?

Comment: Somehow i have to design a registration page and add data in user profile so i just think to create Html page and use Graph api or anything else.

Comment: I need suggestion if i am on wrong way because i don't have any idea to how to find solution.

Comment: You need profiles in Azure AD first to give them access to your SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

External users have to be invited to a SharePoint Online site, there is not a registration option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add user to Azure AD, we need use Graph API to achieve it.

Graph API: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript)

If you want to use JavaScript code, we can using [Microsoft Graph JavaScript Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript).

Comment: I want to add user in SharePoint group, not Azure AD